how do I initialize lateinit property on my Android?
I visit a website and it says I have lateinit property resourcesHandler has not been initialized. What does this mean? and how do I fix it?
I just want the website to work like it did before I got this new phone. Do I have to find a button to push or something? I am not tech savvy.
